# Separate the text in a cell

Tags: excel, sorting, text, split, char

In cell A1 contain (F)(D).

How can I separate cell A1 into cell B1 contain (F) and cell C1 contain (D)

My excel version is 2010.

Thank for help.

Regards,
Joe

Comment: For B1 `=LEFT(A1,3)`, for C1 `=RIGHT(A1,3)`

Answer (score 0):

Formula for `B1` cell-

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(")",A1))
```

Formula for `C1` cell-

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1),100))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Harun quick answer. How about if there are many rows in a column , need to do repeat task. Do I use VBA code to do this repeat job

Comment: You have to drag down the formula as needed. You can go with VBA for one click.